# Firebase random slow fetch on angular-ionic app, Android and iphone

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I try to fetch a firebase object and the request works well half of the time, but is sometimes extremely slow and never terminates.

Activating the Firebase logs didn't yield any errors but, using the chrome inspector, I can see that some `.lp?start=...` requests are `canceled` by the cordova browser.

The app runs Angular 1.4, Ionic 1.1.0, AngularFire 1.1.3 and Firebase 2.2.9. The problem occurs on both Android and iPhone regardless of the version.

My phone is on a good wifi to discard network related issues.

Here is the (maybe) related JS code:

```
var facebookUid = '1213161789'; // result from the facebook native plugin
var ref = new Firebase(config.firebaseurl + '/users');
$firebaseObject(ref.child(facebookUid))
    .$loaded()
    .then(function(firebaseUser) {
       .... // sometimes called
    })
    .catch(function(firebaseUser) {
       .... // never called
    })
;
```

I tried to force long poll instead of web sockets but with no visible changes. The problem originally happened with the plain `Firebase` object, and switching to AngularFire didn't solved it.

This maybe not related but:

- According to the documentation, I also added the following to my config.xml

  - `<allow-intent href="*.firebaseio.com" />`
  - `<allow-intent href="auth.firebase.com" />`
- And this line is in my index.html

  - `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src *">`

Here is what we get after enabling Firebase log :

```
c:0:3: Primary connection is healthy.
p:0: from server: {"r":15,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{}}}
p:0: listen response {"s":"ok","d":{}}
p:0: from server: {"r":16,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}}
p:0: p response {"s":"ok","d":""}
p:0: from server: {"r":17,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}}
p:0: p response {"s":"ok","d":""}
p:0: from server: {"r":18,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}}
p:0: m response {"s":"ok","d":""}
p:0: Browser went offline.  Killing connection.
c:0:3: Closing realtime connection.
c:0:3: Shutting down all connections 
c:0:3:0 Longpoll is being closed.
p:0: data client disconnected
0: onDisconnectEvents
```

It appears that navigator.online is true and when we try to force the connection with Firebase.goOnline() the connection is not restored...